# Flask, flask_login, pytest: How do I set flask_login's current_user?

Tags: python, flask, pytest, flask-login

I am trying to use pytest to unit test my Flask app.  I have the following test case for an endpoint that requires information from `flask_login`'s `current_user`:

```
def test_approval_logic():
    with app.test_client() as test_client:
        app_url_put = '/requests/process/2222'

        with app.app_context():
            user = User.query.filter_by(uid='xxxxxxx').first()
            with app.test_request_context():
                login_user(user)
                user.authenticated = True
                db.session.add(user)

                data = dict(
                    state='EXAMPLE_STATE_NAME',
                    action='approve'
                )
                resp = test_client.put(app_url_put, data=data)
                assert resp.status_code == 200
```

Inside the `test_request_context`, I am able to set `current_user` correctly.  However, this test fails because in the `requests` view where the PUT is handled, there is no logged in user and 500 error results.  The error message is, `AttributeError: 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'email'`.  Can someone explain why `current_user` goes away and how I can set it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using test client to dispatch a request

The current `session` is not bound to `test_client`, so the request uses a new session.

Set the session cookie on the client, so Flask can load the same session for the request:

```py
from flask import session

def set_session_cookie(client):
    val = app.session_interface.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))
    client.set_cookie('localhost', app.session_cookie_name, val)
```

Usage:

```py
# with app.test_client() as test_client:                            # Change these
#     with app.app_context():                                       #
#         with app.test_request_context():                          #
with app.test_request_context(), app.test_client() as test_client:  # to this
    login_user(user)
    user.authenticated = True
    db.session.add(user)

    data = dict(
        state='EXAMPLE_STATE_NAME',
        action='approve'
    )
    set_session_cookie(test_client)  # Add this
    resp = test_client.put(app_url_put, data=data)
```

### About the compatibility of `with app.test_request_context()`

#### i. `with app.test_client()`

`with app.test_client()` preserves the context of requests (Flask doc: [Keeping the Context Around](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/testing/#keeping-the-context-around)), so you would get this error when exiting an inner `with app.test_request_context()`:

> AssertionError: Popped wrong request context. (`<RequestContext 'http://localhost/requests/process/2222' [PUT] of app>` instead of `<RequestContext 'http://localhost/' [GET] of app>`)

Instead, enter `app.test_request_context()` before `app.test_client()` as shown above.

#### ii. `with app.app_context()`

`with app.test_request_context()` already pushes an app context, so `with app.app_context()` is unnecessary.

## Using test request context without dispatching a request

From https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.test_request_context:

> This is mostly useful during testing, where you may want to run a function that uses request data without dispatching a full request.

Usage:

```py
data = dict(
    state='EXAMPLE_STATE_NAME',
    action='approve'
)
with app.test_request_context(data=data):  # Pass data here
    login_user(user)
    user.authenticated = True
    db.session.add(user)

    requests_process(2222)  # Call function for '/requests/process/2222' directly
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that no session cookie is passed in your PUT request.

Here is an example of how I log a user during my tests (I personally user *unittest* instead of *pytest*, so I reduced the code to the strict minimum, but let me know if you want a complete example with *unittest*)

```
from whereyourappisdefined import application
from models import User
from flask_login import login_user

# Specific route to log an user during tests
@application.route('/auto_login/<user_id>')
def auto_login(user_id):
    user = User.query.filter(User.id == user_id).first()
    login_user(user)
    return "ok"

def yourtest():
    application.config['TESTING'] = True # see my side note
    test_client = application.test_client()
    response = test_client.get(f"/auto_login/1")

    app_url_put = '/requests/process/2222'
    data = dict(
        state='EXAMPLE_STATE_NAME',
        action='approve'
    )
    r = test_client.put(app_url_put, data=data)
```

In the documentation we can read:
https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/test/#werkzeug.test.Client

> The use_cookies parameter indicates whether cookies should be stored
> and sent for subsequent requests. This is True by default but passing
> False will disable this behavior.

So during the first request **GET /auto_login/1** the application will receive a session cookie and keep it for further HTTP requests.

**Side note:**

- Enable TESTING in your application (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/testing/)

> During setup, the TESTING config flag is activated. What this does is
> disable error catching during request handling so that you get better
> error reports when performing test requests against the application.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it on my sites:

```
user = User.query.filter_by(user_id='xxxxxxx').one_or_none()
if user:
    user.authenticated = True
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    login_user(user)
else:
   # here I redirect to an unauthorized page, as the user wasn't found
```

I don't know the order is the issue or just the absence of `db.session.commit()`, but I think you need to have done both in order for your put request to work.

Note, also, that I am using a `one_or_none()` because there shouldn't be a possibility of multiple users with the same `user_id`, just a True or False depending on whether a user was found or not.